# Formula field, YTD calculation

Tags: formula-field

I have a requirement where I have to create a calculated field involving the formula as described below. Could I get some guidance how to go about it..?

The functionality in question is to track expense requests.

Custom Object: - myExpObj__c

Fields: -

- Requested Expense Amount -> reqExpAmt__C
- Requester Name -> reqName__C
- Total Expenses Requested YTD -> "totalYTDExpense__C"

Now, I want to calculate the total expense for the current calendar year for a particular requester.

So, as an e.g. when a user is submitting a new expense request, I need to calculate the total expenses requested by that particular requester YTD, for that particular requester.

Something like - totalYTDExpense__C = (reqExpAmt__C year to date, for the reqName__C in question)

Comment: Welcome to salesforce.stackexchange, Please Visit the help center for guidance in asking solid questions: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/asking. Please provide some information on what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too complicated to fit into a simple formula field. You'll need a [roll-up field](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&type=0).

**Non-user records:**

If you're using a contact record associated to a user as with communities or some custom development (many orgs do this in my experience) and the expense report is a master-detail relationship to the contact, a simple roll-up with suffice. Otherwise you may have to create one utilizing a trigger.

**User Records:**

If you're not using a custom contact-user association or your relationship is not master-detail, you'll need to create a trigger on the object to calculate the data and and store the data in a read only field; probably at the user level. We use [LREngine](https://github.com/abhinavguptas/Salesforce-Lookup-Rollup-Summaries) to generate roll-up fields using lookup relationships.

I have not tried to update a user record from within a trigger of a non-setup record. I'd be weary of a [Mixed DML Operation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects_test_methods.htm). (Disclaimer, the documentation only emphasizes test classes so I'm not sure if this will impact non-test classes). If you do get a mixed DML operation, Refer back to my previous answer and create a system to link users up to contacts.

**Formula**

Once you have the roll-up generated, you can reference it in a formula field pretty easily on the expense:

```
reqName__r.totalYTDExpense__c
```

That would pull in the value of the roll-up into the record (which would include the current record after it has been saved).

Comment: Thank you, that's how I ended up solving this. I created another custom object and then did a roll up summary.